# One-placed intersection operator

Tags: semantics, possible-worlds, modal-logic

What is the meaning of a formulation like: "A iff ∩A ⊆p"

A is a set of propositions, p is a specific proposition, and the whole formulation is explicated as "There is no possible world where all members of A are true but p is not".
I know there must be something going on implicitly, but I can't figure out what (am I supposed to read: "A iff ∅∩A ⊆p"? But ∅∩A is the empty set again.)

Another example is: "A iff p⊆∩A"

Any help is appreciated, I've never come across anything like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mathematical contexts a one-place intersection operator usually applies to an indexed set of sets.  Thus A, here, would not merely be a set containing simple objects, but rather A is a set of sets.  Perhaps, for instance, A = { X1, X2, X3 } so that therefore ∩A = X1 ∩ X2 ∩ X3.

Comment: Note the similarity to the syntax in sigma-notation.  If you want to sum a bunch of numbers, you write Σaᵢ this means a₁ + a₂ + ...